# 'json Not a Valid Enumeration for type' Error When Retrieving Standard sObjects with IntelliJ/Jetforcer

Tags: sobject, standard-objects, ide

I use IntelliJ with Jetforcer for Salesforce development. Starting yesterday, I began receiving the following error when trying to retrieve Standard sObjects for my project:

> jsonNot a valid enumeration for type: class com.sforce.soap.partner.SoapType

I've had no troubles retrieving other component types and have been unable to find a resolution to this issue. What would be a reason why I am seeing this error for Standard sObjects?

Comment: Which object does it cause the issue for?

Comment: @dmachop It has the same error for any Standard object I try to retrieve; also the 
Custom objects seem to retrieve fine.

Comment: Let's take an example here. If it fails for Account object, can you see from your workbench what the field definitions are and which one has the soapType = 'json'?

Comment: @dmachop That's the weird thing, when I open workbench none of the fields have a json soapType. Also, when open the .object file in an IntelliJ window -> Right Click -> 'Retrieve Account.object' it works fine. But when I open the Salesforce tab -> 'Retrieve Project...' -> Select Account object that is when I get the error.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Report to Salesforce.

Comment: I think you're trying with the Metadata retrieve. Can you try with the Rest explorer. Utilities->Rest explorer->Put the URL "/services/data/v40/sobjects/Account/describe" (lesser than the latest preview API version 46)->Click expand all. You should see some json under the field soap types.

A shortcut:
https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php?url=/services/data/v40.0/sobjects/Account/describe&autoExec=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in JetForcer 2.0.15

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9238-jetforcer--the-smartest-force-com-ide/update/64221

Answer (score 1):

Since API 46, there is a new FieldType json. You can see an example of standard object using this field type on the field "RecordData" from object "ApiEvent": 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apievent.htm?search_text=ApiEvent

Jetforcer must be using an outdated force-wsc (version >46.0.0) package but trying to get the sObjects from a preview org using API 46.

You should report this bug to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

After raising this as a bug with Salesforce there is know a known issue around the problems that v46 introduced when the Real-Time Event Monitoring Beta is enabled.

Known Issue W-6222075: [DescribeSObject call using the v45.0 Partner API are failing due to a complex type(json) that isn't defined in the WSDL](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?Id=a1p3A000001SHax)